# Use maximum likelihood estimation or "LIKE" method (M3) to compute values under the lower limit of detection?

Tags: r

I have values for a blood test that can only detect values above 10. I have thus the following results, where some are <10 (which I've replaced with NA here):

```
day1 <- c(49, NA, 55, 30, NA, NA, NA, 43, 15, 36, 37, NA, 22, 16, 14, 35, 33, 72, 18, NA, 15, 75, 97, 15, NA, 51, 17, NA, 43, 73)
day2 <- c(25, 10, 13, 22, 10, 14, 19, 42, 13, NA, 31, 56, 18, 45, NA, 79, NA, 31, 22, NA, 19, 140, 47, 41, NA, 110, 53, 12, 12, 43)
day3 <- c(10, NA, 18, 25, 14, 12, 14, 39, NA, NA, 22, NA, NA, 15, 34, 33, NA, 64, 49, NA, NA, 45, 75, NA, NA, 38, NA, 35, 69, 15)
day4 <- c(10, NA, NA, NA, 86, 18, NA, 11, NA, NA, 72, 25, 25, 34, 13, 37, 36, 23, 50, NA, 45, 140, 120, 18, NA, 49, 36, 31, 199, 122)
```

These 0 values could thus be anywhere between 0 and 9.999…. I've understood that there are many ways to deal with these type of values: treat them as NA, use 10, or replace them with 10/sqrt(2).

However, some sources suggest other methods, claimed to be better:

- **MLE**: https://www.genasis.cz/time-series/index.php?pg=home--treatment-of-values-under-loq
- **"LIKE" method using M3**: Keizer RJ, Jansen RS, Rosing H, Thijssen B, Beijnen JH, Schellens JH, Huitema AD. Incorporation of concentration data below the limit of quantification in population pharmacokinetic analyses. Pharmacol Res Perspect. 2015 Mar;3(2):e00131. doi: [10.1002/prp2.131](https://doi.org/10.1002%2Fprp2.131). Epub 2015 Mar 25. PMID: 26038706; PMCID: PMC4448983.

How can I use one of these methods to estimate these values? Can I use the mle(), nll_BLOQ() or blloq_IQRdataGENERAL() function?

Kind regards

Edit:
This is the distribution of the data
[image: Distribution of the data]

Edit 2:
The analysis planned after estimation of these values is a Wilcoxon signed-rank test comparing the difference between day 1 and 2 with the difference between day 3 and 4. I.e.,:

```
wilcox.test((day2-day1), (day4-day3), paired=T, alternative=c("two.sided"))
```

Comment: As the page you link to states, "some assumptions about the statistical distribution of the concentration values have to be done".  So what distributional assumptions would you like to make?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Limey. The actual data that I analyze seems to have right-skewed distribution. Is that enough of an assumption or would it need to be more detailed?

Comment: Is this your whole data set?  What do kinds of analyses/tests do you intend to do with these data?

Comment: Dear @BenBolker: Thank you for your time! I have 30 participants with these measurements made at 4 instances (lets call them day 1, 2, 3 and 4), thus, in total 120 measurements. Afterwards, I will compare using paired t test the difference between day 1 and 2 and day 3 and 4, of these values, to see if there is a difference. I also added a plot of the distribution of the data above.

Comment: @BenBolker: I've now updated the data above with 30 values of 4 days to better reflect the actual data. Also, I added the test (a Wilcoxon signed-rank test, rather than a t test, given the non-normal distributions).

Comment: A signed rank test can deal with ties, and, in my understanding, being tied at the detection limit is all we can state when *comparing treatments* (no matter whether we substitute the NAs with the detection limit, its half, square root etc.). Adding random variation trough sophisticated imputation might thus turn up slightly better estimates of group means, but won't improve the validity of group comparisons by (partly random) ranks. My 2c ;-)